# dc.js Stacked Bar Chart having only one column and with elastic X Axis is not rendered properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, dc.js, crossfilter

I have created a stacked bar chart using dc.js and crossfilter. I am using a time dimnesion along the x-axis and has also made it elastic. But it seems like the chart is not rendering properly when there is just one column (either because of data or bceause of cross filtering by other charts) in the stacked bar chart.

Before:[image: Before Filtering]

After filtering graph shows no column or may be it is hidden:[image: Graph shows no column or may be it is hidden]

As a workaround, I added an extra month to the min and max date to the data as dummy data but even that doesn't help. So I decided to do away with the elastic x-axis. But without an elastic x-axis the chart looks very sparse & poor when the data is filtered.

I have searched across many posts but I don't seem to find any helpful solution. I will be glad if someone could point me in the right direction. This is how I have setup my chart currently

```
  chart
  .width(768)
  .height(480)
  .margins({
    left: 80,
    top: 20,
    right: 10,
    bottom: 80
  })
  .x(d3.time.scale()).elasticX(true)
  .round(d3.time.month.round)
  .alwaysUseRounding(true)
  .xUnits(d3.time.months)
  .brushOn(false)
  .xAxisLabel('Months')
  .yAxisLabel("Expected Sales (in thousands)")
  .dimension(dimMonthYear)
  .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
  .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
  .legend(dc.legend().x(130).y(30).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
  .group(combinedGroup, "Understand", sel_stack(0))
  .stack(combinedGroup, "Propose", sel_stack(1))
  .stack(combinedGroup, "Negotiate", sel_stack(2))
  .stack(combinedGroup, "Decide", sel_stack(3))
  .stack(combinedGroup, "Deliver", sel_stack(4))
  .centerBar(true)
  .elasticY(true)
  .elasticX(true)
  .renderlet(function(chart) {
    chart.selectAll("g.x text").attr('dx', '-30').attr(
      'dy', '-7').attr('transform', "rotate(-60)");
  });
```

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NewMonk/8pc0p1we/26/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are running into this issue: [elasticX for linear domain doesn't include the rightmost bar](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/792)

(Or a similar issue.)

dc.js takes its boundaries very literally, and it also computes them literally, so much that it doesn't take the width of its own bars into consideration.

One simple way to work around this is to add some padding:

```
.xAxisPadding(1).xAxisPaddingUnit('month')
```

Since you are aggregating by month, this will make sure there is always a month to the left and right of the calculated domain (which will be of width 0 when there is only one bar).

Of course, you will end up with that single bar filling the chart:
[image: big bar]

So you might want to calculate the domain manually, in `preRedraw`, until dc.js gets better at this.

Fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/97h8kd5g/2/

Comment: `.xAxisPadding(1).xAxisPaddingUnit('month')` works for me beautifully. I am okay with one column filling up the chart for the time being.
As a side note, I am really thankful to dc.js and more than that to you for helping me understand this wonderful library more and more. Cheers